# How to create a two-column matrix in rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm using rpy2 to run a method from an R library. According to the documentation:

```
method_name(x, range.x)

x: a two-column numeric matrix.
range.x: a list containing two vectors.
```

And it includes an example:

```
data(geyser, package="MASS")
x <- cbind(geyser$duration, geyser$waiting)
est <- method_name(x, range.x)
```

I checked the type of `geyser$duration` and `geyser$waiting` and both are `double`. I also tried replacing `geyser$duration` and `geyser$waiting` by `g = c(.016, 2.15, 4.00)` and `h = c(.012, 2.11, 2.50)` in R, and the code still works.

In my current Python code, I have:

```
import numpy as np
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector, FloatVector, ListVector # I tried these before too
from rpy2.robjects import numpy2ri, pandas2ri

numpy2ri.activate()
pandas2ri.activate()

base = rpackages.importr(('base'))

a = np.array([1.2, 2.1, 2.5]); b = np.array([5.2, 1.3, 2.15])
x = base.cbind(base.c(a), base.c(b))

ranges = base.range(x)
result = method_name(x, ranges)
```

As you can see, I'm trying to make my code as similar to the example as possible. However, I can't make the method work. I get the error `Error in seq.default(a[2L], b[2L], length = M[2L])` which probably has to do with a problem in the arguments.

There's and obvious problem with `ranges` because it contains just two values, the minimum and maximum of `x`, however, it should contain two minimum values and to maximum values (one pair for each column of the matrix). I can achieve that by doing this:

```
ranges = base.cbind(base.range(a), base.range(b))
```

But this implies that there's a problem with the way I'm creating the matrix. Otherwise, I would get two pairs of values just by using `base.range(x)`.

I also tried `x = robjects.r.matrix(x, ncol = 2)` but didn't work. I still get just a global minimum and maximum value for the whole matrix when calling `range`.

What is the correct way of creating this matrix so that the method can run?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of the `range` function, **it accepts as input vectors** (one dimensional arrays). Thus, it would work by applying it to each column of your matrix or by applying it first directly to the `a` and `b` elements as you have mentioned. Thus, you second approach should work

```
# Define a,b vectors
a = np.array([1.2, 2.1, 2.5]); b = np.array([5.2, 1.3, 2.15])

# Calculate vector ranges
range_a = base.range(base.c(a))
range_b = base.range(base.c(b))

# Define the matrix 
x = base.cbind(base.c(a), base.c(b))
print(x)
>>> [[1.2  5.2 ]
    [2.1  1.3 ]
    [2.5  2.15]]

# Define the ranges
ranges = base.cbind(range_a, range_b)
print(ranges)
>>> [[1.2 1.3]
    [2.5 5.2]]
```